# i cannot access my link on my php page

Tags: php

i'm working on a `view_category.php` page for my forum but i am having a small problem my link is not working i'm logging in but the page is showing that im not logged in its treating me like im a guest just viewing the forum hence i can not create a topic on the forum,my create_topic.php link can not be accessed.

here is my code below

```
// Assign local variables
$cid = $_GET['cid'];

// Check to see if the person accessing this page is logged in
if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    $logged = " | <a href='create_topic.php?cid=".$cid."'>Click Here To Create A Topic</a>";
} else {
    $logged = " | Please log in to create topics in this forum.";
}
```

why is this happening??

i just included

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

and this the output

```
 array(2) { ["username"]=> string(7) "mura" ["password"]=> string(4) "1234" }
```

Comment: your `session['uid']` is not being set. do a `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see if its in there. If it's not, you'll have to figure out why it's not being set. You probably also need a session_start() on your page.

Comment: Sounds like you aren't setting the session correctly when you log a user in.

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` at the beginning of your file and are you setting your `$_SESSION['uid']` variable?

Comment: @War10ck yes i do have session_start();but if i put $_SESSION['uid']; im geting the undefined index error

Comment: @theuserkaps Do you mind posting your output of `var_dump($_SESSION);` for us to take a look at?

Comment: @War10ck ok let me post it

Comment: @War10ck this is the output array(2) { ["username"]=> string(7) "mura" ["password"]=> string(4) "1234" }

Comment: well, you put your username in the "username", not "uid"

Comment: @theuserkaps There is your problem. See the answer I posted below. You're referencing a variable that has never been set.

Comment: You're spitting query string data directly into the page. You are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `session_start();` at the header of your file

Comment: i have a session_start(); at the hearder file

Comment: So you probably have some problems with your session values. Show me an output of `var_dump($_SESSION)`. Nobody among us knows how your authorisation system works.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) output gives me array(2) { ["username"]=> string(7) "mulizwa" ["password"]=> string(4) "1234" }

Comment: Well there's your problem; `$_SESSION['uid']` doesn't exist on your session. Did you mean to use `$_SESSION['username']`, or did you want to set uid upon login?

Comment: i want to set up uid upon login,how can i do it?

Comment: Find the place in tour code where you setting up session username and password (btw why do you store password in sessions?) and place there `$_SESSION['uid'] = $id`, where $id is the value of the just logged in user, I do not know how exactly you can get it in your app.

Answer (score 1):

change `if (isset($_SESSION['uid']))` to `if (isset($_SESSION['username']))` ?

your current session information about the user is stored in the `$_SESSION['username']`, not `$_SESSION['uid']`, so you can either use the username to check if the user is logged in, or put the uid in the session when the user logs in.

BTW, don't put your password in session.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
isset($_SESSION['uid'])
```

But when you do a var_dump, that value is not in the dump. You need to added it to your session at some point (before you do the isset()).

On an unrelated note, it is not safe to save passwords within sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you've just shown it appears you've found the problem. You've got two variables set:

```
"username"
"password"
```

In your solution above though you're trying to reference:

```
$_SESSION['uid']
```

which doesn't appear to exist. Either you are not creating this variable or it is not being set properly. Either way, the logic is doing what it should. The variable is not set, therefore you are not ever going to see the 'create' link. Try changing the logic to point to one of the two variables you already have set or assign a value to the "$_SESSION['uid']" variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to set up uid upon login,how can i do it?

Comment: What do you want it set to? Does each user have a 'uid'? To set the session variable you simply use `$_SESSION['uid'] = < some value >;` just like a regular assignment expression. Because you have `session_start();` at the top of your page, the variable will carry over from page to page.